# Julia | Array Element as an Argument of Another Array

Tags: julia

I have a problem with indexing when an array element is an argument to another array. It results in an "invalid index 1.0" error. For example:

```
i = 0    

for l in 1:length
    for s in 1:ser
        for x in 1:s

        i = i + 1

        arr1[i] = x

        end
    end
end



for ts in 1:tiser

arr2[ts] = arr3[arr1[ts]]

end
```

Here is the code that you can copy to a REPL and find the error. What I get is an index error.

```
arr1 = Array{Float64,1}(1500)   
arr2 = Array{Float64,1}(10000)
arr3 = Array{Float64,1}(10000)


for z in 1:100

    arr3[z] = 1 + z

end


i = 0    

for l in 1:100
    for s in 1:5
        for x in 1:s

        i = i + 1

        arr1[i] = x

        end
    end
end



for ts in 1:10000

    arr2[ts] = arr3[arr1[ts]]

end

println(arr2[3])
```

Thank you

Comment: I can't tell from the question what the problem is. Ideally you would post a minimum working example (MWE), which is something that we can just copy and paste into the REPL which generates the error. Also, you appear to be using `length` as a variable name. This is not a good idea, since `length` is already a frequently used function name.

Comment: Thank you I will do this. It gives me the error of "invalid index 1.0".  Does this help?

Comment: From the error it sounds like you are trying to index the array with a float instead of an integer, but hard to tell without a MWE.

Comment: I uploaded the MWE in the questions section

Comment: @fredrikekre here you are.

Comment: @ColinTBowers. The MWE is ready

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the floating number from `arr1` to use it as index. I modified the Minimum Working Example to work:

```
arr1 = Array{Float64,1}(1500)   
arr2 = Array{Float64,1}(10000)
arr3 = Array{Float64,1}(10000)


for z in 1:100

    arr3[z] = 1 + z

end


i = 0    

for l in 1:100
    for s in 1:5
    for x in 1:s
        i = i + 1
        arr1[i] = x
    end
    end
end

println(arr1[1:20])

for ts in 1:10000
    from_arr1_as_index=Int(arr1[(ts-1)%1500+1])
    arr2[ts] = arr3[from_arr1_as_index]
end


println(arr2[3])
```

Comment: Thank you, but you can also define the arrays as Int64!